# For OpenHab Zwave Bundle where is the underlying code for MultiLevelSensor to display its readings?

Tags: java, sensors, openhab, z-wave

This is an odd question because, typically you can get log info and such not to mention have the inner structure of Openhab already done, but I have extracted simply the OpenHab Z-wave Bundle and all the required library, to run a simulation of a multi-sensor `Aeon Labs MultiSensor Model:DSB05-ZWUS`.

The controller I'm using is an `AEOTEC Z-Stick S2`, and I'm launching The OpenHab bundle through an OSGI system set up with Maven, on a local machine. I've tested out a binary switch to turn off and on a light, which was fairly simple by sending message of either OFF or ON which is 00 or FF, but for the multi-level sensor you have to send it message to retrieve information.

I can't seem to find the work flow since there is no GUI example of how one would go about obtaining all the sensor readings. I've dug deep into the code and from what I understand, the multi-level sensor has enum types that hold a number and the corresponding sensor type.

I was able to getMessage(sensorType) and it returned to me something like this for example: `SendData (0x13)`, `type = Request (0x00`), `playload = 0D 02 31 04 01`. I have suspicions to believe that the playload is information that is use to determine what the sensor's readings are, but I can't find any resource to decode that.

I was however able to find a Converter class: `ZWaveMultiLevelSensorConverter.java` that has a method called `public void handleEvent(ZWaveCommandClassValueEvent event, Item item, Map<String,String> arguments)` that has a single conversion for temperature readings, but I'm unsure what would go into the parameter.

So the specific question I have is what is the specific method that gives the reading for each sensor type (ex: temperature), and if possible what is the work flow of the code?

Resource: https://github.com/openhab/openhab/tree/master/bundles/binding/org.openhab.binding.zwave

Answer (score 1):

## Configuration

First, you need to configure your device to send the information you want. Add "Habmin" ([HABmin](https://github.com/cdjackson/HABmin)) as a plugin to configure the sensor. Key things to set:

1. Wake up 10 minutes when batteries are inserted - it's helpful to turn this on
2. Enable Motion Sensor - On if you want motion detection
3. On Time - When motion is detected, the device will send an "on"
   notification. After a certain number of seconds (this setting), it
   will send an "off" notification (see #7 below).
4. Group 1 Reports: Set this to 225 (decimal), which is 11100001. A 1 in a bit says send that reading. Bit 0 is battery level, 5 is temperature, 6 is relative humidity and 7 is luminance.
5. Group 1 Interval: How often the report is sent.
6. Make sure you have an Association set for Group 1 to Node 1, your Zstick
   controller.
7. Command Options - I set this to "Basic" and I add another device (on/off lamp controller) as an Association for Group 1. When motion is detected, the Basic report causes the lamp controller to turn on and when the motion period expires, it sends another basic report to turn off. This happens among the devices without any software running in the background. Your ZStick also gets a basic report which triggers an Event notification (see below).

## Polling

Because the device is battery-operated, you can't poll it for readings whenever you want. It will send a report to Group 1 (your ZStick) with the sensor readings at the time interval you specify in the configuration. Otherwise, it sleeps. However, if the motion detection is on, it will immediately respond to motion.

## Coding

OpenHAB uses the OpenZWave library (see [Z-Wave Binding](https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Z-Wave-Binding)). Everything funnels through a single Manager class. Basically, you listen for events such as nodes being added or removed, or values being updated. Download the OpenZWave Control Panel ([OpenZWave Control Panel](https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave-control-panel)) and look at "ozwcp.cpp" to see what you need to do. I've done everything in C++ -- I'm not sure about Java.

When the multisensor sends a report with readings, you get a **Notification::Type_ValueChanged**. For example:

```
// this is the node number that triggered the event
uint8 const nid = notification->GetNodeId();

// this is the internal value that identifies what was changed
ValueID const vid = notification->GetValueID();

// this is the English version of what was changed
string vLabel = Manager::Get()->GetValueLabel(vid);
```

The vLabel will be "temperature", "relative_humidity", "Luminance", "battery_level" or "sensor" for motion period on/off.

A Basic report when motion is detected triggers a **Notification::Type_NodeEvent**.

Comment: Note that openhanded doesn't use the openzwave library. It's written in maybe Java.

Comment: @cdjackson: what's openhanded? he's talking about OpenHAB

Comment: Openhanded is what you get if you don't check an iPhone autocorrect for openhab. :). I'm the main author of the openhab Zwave binding.

Comment: LOL, that explains it. Great job on the binding, BTW. And you're right, it's in Java. The code I included is really for OpenZWave, not OpenHAB.